# How do I solve algebraic equations that are complex?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Let say I have the equation $$e^{2x}(2x^3-5x^2-10x+7)=7$$
What would be a good approach to solve this question? I have tried solving by hand but it doesn't seem possible, and I've tried online algebra calculators but they cannot solve. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can’t solve that equation only using Elementary Algebra. That equation has three irrational roots and a complex root.

Comment: I used desmos to graph the equation and it works out to be three points at x=0, x=0.242 and x=3.615

Comment: Yes, x=0 is yet another solution. But Elementary Algebra doesn’t provide the tools needed to solve those kind of equations.

Comment: There are many systems that simply cannot be solved by hand and require numerical analysis to approximate solutions to.  Yours would be one such example, but other examples can look even simpler than that.  For example, $x^x=5$ would require the use of the lambert-w function, a non-elementary function, to use to find the solutions.  The study of (*abstract*) algebra increases our repitoire of equations we can solve, but by no means covers all possibilities.

Comment: So in conclusion this is not possible to solve by hand?